# Google chat bot Mention user in space

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hangouts, google-chat

I have a chatbot and I am trying to make the bot mention a user in a space. For example, we have:

> @googlechatBot Hello

> User said "@googlechatBot Hello"

But I would like you to mention the user in the answer. Something like that

> @googlechatBot Hello

> @User said "@googlechatBot Hello"

The code I use is from the template found in the documentation.

```
function onMessage(event) {
  var name = "";

  if (event.space.type == "DM") {
    name = "You";
  } else {
    name = event.user.displayName;
  }
  var message = name + " said \"" + event.message.text + "\"";

  return { "text": message };
}
```

Comment: Hi there @Gamaor! What is your question? Could you please describe what is wrong with that code?

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried this approach?

```
{
    "text": "Hey <users/123456789012345678901>! Thank you for using _Pizza bot!_"
}
```

As described here https://developers.google.com/chat/api/guides/message-formats/basic?hl=en#messages_that_mention_specific_users